# How can i make sure that if i closed the program and run again it will create the new file in a new directory?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this method:

```
private void CreateAnimatedGif(bool ToCreate)
{
    string combined = null;
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(sf);
    FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles("*.gif");
    if (simtest == fi.Length - 1)
    {
        simtest = 0;
    }

    if (AnimatedGifFiles.Count == 0)
        startTime = DateTime.Now;

    if (ToCreate == false)
    {
        combined = Path.Combine(sf, fi[simtest].FullName);
        AnimatedGifFiles.Add(combined);//last_file);
        simtest += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (AnimatedGifFiles.Count > 1)
        {
            rainEventCounter += 1;
            AnimatedGifDirectoryEvent = "Rain event " + rainEventCounter.ToString();
            string eventDir = Path.Combine(AnimatedGifDirectory, AnimatedGifDirectoryEvent);

            if (!Directory.Exists(eventDir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(eventDir);
            }

            string outputFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                eventDir,
                string.Format(
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "Event-{0:yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss}_{1:yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss}.gif", startTime, DateTime.Now
                )
            );

            unfreezWrapper1.MakeGIF(AnimatedGifFiles, outputFile, 80, true);
        }

        AnimatedGifFiles.Clear();
    }
}
```

In this part i'm creating the directory each time to create inside the `outputFile`.

```
rainEventCounter += 1;
AnimatedGifDirectoryEvent = "Rain event " + rainEventCounter.ToString();
string eventDir = Path.Combine(AnimatedGifDirectory, AnimatedGifDirectoryEvent);
if (!Directory.Exists(eventDir))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(eventDir);
}
```

The problem is when i'm running the program over again then `rainEventCounter` is 0 so it will put the new `outputFile` in the first existing directory.
What i want it to do is to check if there are any directories in `AnimatedGifDirectory`:

OK edit:

I added now to the top of the class a variable string[] dirs
And in the class constructor i did:

```
dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(AnimatedGifDirectory);
```

So now when i'm running my program there are 0 sub directories.
But then i run the program over again and there are for example 3 directories.
Now `dirs` contain 3 directories.

Now i want that next time `AnimatedGifDirectoryEvent` will be "Rain event 4" as sub directory name and not "Rain event 1" again.

Of course if `dirs` length is 0 then `AnimatedGifDirectoryEvent` will be "Rain event 1".

Comment: `rainEventCounter = dirs.Length`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the count of directories in your root directory in the `dirs` variable. Use `dirs.Length + 1` to set the new directory name.

```
AnimatedGifDirectoryEvent = "Rain event " + (dirs.Length + 1);
```

Comment: This should work, but If some directories are deleted, then it could return an already existing name.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple ways to get it. First you can get the `Length` of your Directory array and then return that. Like:

```
public static int GetNextNumber(string directoryPath)
{
    var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath);
    return dirs.Length + 1;
}
```

Or you can parse the digit from your directory name to int, get the `Max` from that and return that + 1.

```
public static int GetNextNumberWithParsing(string directoryPath)
{
    var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath);
    var number = dirs.Select(r => int.Parse(r.Replace("Rain event ", ""))).Max();
    return number + 1;
}
```

and then call it in your application like:

```
rainEventCounter = GetNextNumberWithParsing(AnimatedGifDirectory);
```

The only problem in using first method is if your directories get deleted *(may be due to some cleanup job)*, then Length *could*  return an invalid directory name. Consider if you have directories like:

```
Raise event 1
Raise event 2
Raise event 3
Raise event 4
```

Then if you use `dir.Length` it would return 4 and then you can use `dir.Length + 1` for next name.

But if directories 1 and 2 gets deleted in that case you will get a Length of 2 and your next directory number will be `3`, and now it will throw an error since a directory with that name already exists.